# Django 1.11 CSRF token is not generated

Tags: python, django, csrf

I'm new in Django, When I try to use csrf, I didn't event see the csrfmidderwaretoken generate in html code. Please someone help me out:)
blow is clips of my code:

urls.py:

```
`url(r'^register/$', register, name="register"),`
```

views.py:

```
def register(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            if not (User.objects.filter(username=username)):
                User.objects.create(username=username, password=password)
                User.save()
                return render(request, "register.html", {"status":True})
        else:
            return render_to_response('register.html')
```

register.html:
[image: Template Html Code Link]

And what shows out is this:
[image: Appearance on site]

Django 1.11, Python3.6.
Can somebody help me check this, much appreciated in advance.

Comment: You should use `create_user` instead of `create` so that the password is correctly hashed. The `save()` call after you have created the object is not required.

Comment: Is `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` defined in your `settings.MIDDLEWARE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `render_to_response` in the final line. It's obsolete. Change it to `render` so that context processors (including csrf) work.

```
return render(request, 'register.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

`render_to_response` is deprecated. Please use `render()` instead.

```
return render('register.html')
```